# is file descriptor table self maintained by per-process

Tags: operating-system, system-calls, file-descriptor

Wiki says that

> In the traditional implementation of Unix, file descriptors index into a per-process file descriptor table maintained by the kernel, that in turn indexes into a system-wide table of files opened by all processes, called the file table.

Does kernel only return a fd when you do an open syscall, or rather in per-process
it also creates something like fd table for the callee process?

Is fd unique in system-wide? I'm really curious what happens down there when we open or write to files?

Comment: Linux is open-source. Go look.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this you can think like, when you open a any file, pipe or device file, they all have different drivers associated with it, so to know which driver to use while using read, write, lseek etc. and to link the inode to update last accessed or locking the file, Kernel creates a data structure associated with every file.

And also other background processes may be running, so to manage these files, kernel creates a table of those data structure and return index number of that data structure row in its table. To that we call a file descriptor.

So as per your question, single row created every time when we call open, it can be multiple time in single process or can be in different process, always returned FD associated with a row in table in kernel is always different.